# How to print all of the key/value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Given a dictionary `myDictionary`, write a function that prints all of the key/value pairs of the dictionary, one per line, in the following format:

```
key: value
key: value
key: value
```

Use the following function header:

```
def printKeyValuePairs(myDictionary):
```

For example, if

```
myDictionary = {'The Beatles':10, 'Bob Dylan':10, 'Radiohead':5}
```

your function would print

```
The Beatles: 10
Bob Dylan: 10
Radiohead: 5
```

Comment: do your homeworks on your own.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in myDictionary:
    print("{}: {}".format(key, myDictionary[key]))
```

Comment: that just printed our the numbers, is there a way to also print out the artists name with the colon before the key

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the artists names and a colon.

Comment: That one worked could you possible explain why you used the empty brackets and the format function?

Comment: It's just an easy way to format strings, you didn't have to use the format function to accomplish this. But you can read more about what it is here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Answer (score 1):

I read on SO somewhere there is a good reason not to either access dictionary values using `myDictionary[key]` over the following, or visa-versa, but I can't recall where (or if I'm remembering correctly).

```
for key, value in myDictionary.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

There are essentially two (modern) ways to do string formatting in Python, both covered in great detail [here][1]:

- `"var1: {}, var2: {}".format("VAR1", "VAR2")`
- `f"var1: {"VAR1"}, var2: {"VAR2"}"`

Both yield `var1: var1, var2:VAR2`, but the latter is only supported in Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple function that prints all the key value pairs in a dictionary:

```
def printKeyValuePairs(myDictionary):
"""prints each key, value pair in a line"""
    for key, val in myDictionary.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, val))
```

if the a dictionary has the following key, value pairs:

```
my_dict = {'The Beatles':10, 'Bob Dylan':10, 'Radiohead':5}
```

if we call the function defined above, we get the following output:

```
printKeyValuePairs(my_dict)
The Beatles: 10 
Bob Dylan: 10 
Radiohead: 5
```